# Determining the Wronskian from given information

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

**My attempt:**

I understand part (a) and (b), however I am unsure as to what part (c) is asking me. Is it as simple as $p(x)=x-1$ therefore $W(x) = ce^{-(x^2-x+c)}$?

Therefore for part (d), we require the Wronskian to be nonnegative therefore $c \ne 0$.

Is this a valid solution to question part (c) and (d)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the equation $(4)$ in standard form first:

$$ y'' + \frac{(x-1)}{x}y' + \frac{3}{x}y = 0. $$

We're given that $x > 0$ so this is fine. Here $p(x) = (x-1)/x$, which yields

$$W(x) = c \exp\left(-\int \frac{(x-1)}{x} \,dx \right) = c xe^{-x}.$$

For part $(d)$, your reasoning is correct; we only need to have $c \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Would I be correct in using variation of parameters for part (b)?

Comment: @L.JOE For part $(b)$ we have the first order equation $W'(x) + p(x)W(x) = 0$, so an integrating factor suffices (it's even separable).

Comment: I see! I understand that, except for the $W'(x)$ part. Why is that the derivative of the Wronskian? Thanks!

Comment: @L.JOE The Wronskian is $W(x) = y_1y_2' - y_2y_1'$. Differentiate that and you'll get $y_1y_2'' - y_2y_1''$ by the product rule.